# Flex Builder 4 Spark equivalent to Yahoo Astra Flash Layout Dragbar

Tags: user-interface, flash, apache-flex, layout, flex-spark

I am currently looking at a couple of ways to integrate UI components into my current Flash project. I usually use Flash Develop and I have recently been evaluating the Yahoo Astra Flash library and I really like the following example (especially the horizontal and vertical drag bars):

http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/layout-containers/examples/FeedReader/FeedReader.html

Today I was evaluating the new Spark components in Flex Builder 4 and looked to building an interface in a similar way. I liked the overall workflow system of FB4 and it feels like my most preferable IDE (eclipse version).

Question, is there was a way that I can duplicate the same kind of screen mechanisims found in the above example, using the Spark layout system in FB4. I've been playing with the components, and nothing is jumping out at me as prebuilt layout drag bars per-se, and if there isn't anything prebuilt, is there anyway that this could be acheived simply?! :)

Any help, really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a new spark component, but you can still use the old mx:HDividedBox and mx:VDividedBox to create the layout like this

```
<mx:HDividedBox height="100%" width="100%">
    <mx:Panel width="25%" height="100%"/> 
    <mx:VDividedBox height="100%" width="100%">
        <mx:Panel height="50%" width="100%"/>
        <mx:Panel height="50%" width="100%"/>
    </mx:VDividedBox>
</mx:HDividedBox>
```

Comment: Amazing.... Perfect, strangly these mx components are not visible in the component section of FB4. Is it possible to be able to add them do you know!? Many thanks indeed! :)

Comment: When in design mode they should be in the "Layout" folder of the components panel in FB4.

Comment: Unfortunatly, they are not available. I seem to have a mixture of spark and mx components but not the divided boxes as in yur example (and critically, maybe more). I've installed the FB4 demo today using the FB4 plugin with the pre-bundled Ganymede Eclipse so i've done nothing weird.

Comment: Ah, ok, it seems that the panel was defaulted to 'Only show recommended components'

That's a little bit of a concern, any knowledge of why this might be a stipulation? Potential bugs or just something like skinning?! Cheers for your other help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the MX Containers [HDividedBox or VDividedBox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e54.html).  I do not believe there is a spark equivalent, but you should be able to use the MX containers with the spark containers without any problems.